# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in /homepages/

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am trying to install my page but this error is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in /homepages/14/db1/htdocs/bonoboapp/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php:91 
Stack trace: #0 /homepages/14/db1/htdocs/bonoboapp/system/database/DB_driver.php(115): CI_DB_mysql_driver->db_pconnect() 
#1 /homepages/14/db1/htdocs/bonoboapp/system/database/DB.php(148): CI_DB_driver->initialize() 
#2 /homepages/14/db1/htdocs/bonoboapp/carpooling/core/MY_Router.php(111): DB() 
#3 /homepages/14/db1/htdocs/bonoboapp/carpooling/core/MY_Router.php(68): My_Router->_get_db_route('login') 
#4 /homepages/14/db1/htdocs/bonoboapp/system/core/Router.php(170): My_Router->_parse_routes() 
#5 /homepages/14/db1/htdocs/bonoboapp/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(173): CI_Router->_set_routing() 
#6 /homepages/14/db1/htdocs/bonoboapp/index.php(213): require_once('/homepages/14/d...') 
#7 {main} thrown in /homepages/14/db1/htdocs/bonoboapp/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php on line 91
```

Could you helpme please.

Comment: You're probably trying to run obsolete code on a current version of PHP.

Comment: according to this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php, "mysql_pconnect() This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0". Use `mysqli` or `pdo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're using Codeigniter, this error is most likely using their Database Class and drivers so you're not using PHP's MySQL functions directly.

Therefore, all you need to do is change

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

to

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

> Add following settings for your **database.php** file

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => '',
'username' => '',
'password' => '',
'database' => '',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Good catch on the `CI_` classes ;)

Comment: Yeah, noticed that `CI_DB_driver`  ;)

Comment: Ok, i'm use this code, but the problem is persistent:

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'carpooling';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';

Comment: Updating my answer for additional value.

Comment: Thanks the final code:
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'carpooling',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
It's correct? 
Appear the same error

Comment: it should work, whats your mysql version?

Comment: Hello. i'm use MySQL 5.5 and the PHP 7.0. thanks.